# Methods for calculating an optimal distance threshold for fisherfaces. Source code provided

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, face-recognition

I've been working on a face recognizer based on the fisherfaces implementation (the pre opencv 2.4 version) provided by bytefish. The actual fisherfaces algorithm is the same, the differences are mostly convenience ones:

-Image/storage compression.

-Classifications by string opposed to ints.

-Inclusive predictions (multiple results sorted by a percentage).

Note: The percentage is calculated with: percent = 1.0 - (lowdist/distthreshold)
Where lowdist is the lowest euclidian distance between a src matrix (the test face image) and a matrix in a projection set (the trained face images) and distthreshold is the maximum distance allowed.

The inclusive predictions are where I'm having trouble. I haven't found a decent way to calculate an optimal threshold to use. Currently I'm just choosing 2200.0 as a random value to test with. This of course produces a lot of flaky results, especially when face images are coming from random sources with different lighting and resolutions.

So my question is: Is there a way to calculate an optimal distance threshold to use with fisherfaces?

I've provided the source code to the recognizer below.

Ignore the method, "FBaseLDARecognizer::calculateOptimalThreshold", it isn't finished. The goal was to add a group of faces to the recognizer and then test against an unknown set of faces with known classifications and get the maximum and minimum correct distances. That is as far as I got, I haven't thought of a useful way to use that data yet. So currently it always returns 0.0.

Note: This is not finished, there are a few performance issues I've yet to clean up. Also, this code isn't commented. If further explanation is needed please let me know and I can comment and reupload the files.

Source Files:

[Header](http://pastebin.com/GuSd2gRz)

[Source](http://pastebin.com/unxd6FYM)

Comment: This question is outdated. The sources were uploaded to an external source instead of directly added to the question. This question can never be replied, even if it appears to be an interesting problem.

Comment: I can reupload the source files if you want? They're big so I figured reading them in the question would be a pain.